# Passing an array to .map() errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is peculiar.

I'm passing an array consisting of a single object to a React component's Render method:

```
let content = this.state.links.map(link => { // eslint-disable-line
  return (
    <li key={link._id}>
      <a href={link.link}>{link.title}</a>
    </li>
  );
});

return (
  <h3>
    <ul>
      {content}
    </ul>
  </h3>
);
```

This is the output of `this.state.links` :

`[{"_id":"56f9b418657c2d2353611b0f","link":"https://facebook.github.io/flux/","title":"flux"}]`

It's an array with one object. How come I'm getting this error?:

[image]

UPDATE: I've kinda found the problematic code:

It's fine going into here:

`const _getAppState = () => { // eslint-disable-line
  return {
    links: LinkStore.getAll(),
  };
};`

LinkStore.getAll() still returns an array with an object.

Then the next time we call the above function:

  `onChange() {
    console.log('4. In the View', _getAppState());
    // this.setState(_getAppState());
  }`

[image]

Still not totally sure when and how it transforms into a string. If you want to dig into the code and see for yourself, [here is the repo](https://github.com/ilrein/Atlas).

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(typeof this.state.links)`?

Comment: It's coming out as a string! o.O

Comment: What does the compiled code look like?

Comment: Do you need to use JSON.parse to turn you links into an object.  It seems based on your comment that links contains as string which does not have a map function.  Try, where ever you are assigning this.state.links, to run JSON.parse(value) when assigning.

Comment: I created a https://jsfiddle.net/32be8Lwo/1/ that shows the difference.

Comment: Check if your server is sending the correct content-type headers. If it is, then you need to `JSON.parse(body)` here https://github.com/ilrein/Atlas/blob/master/src/components/API.js#L21

Comment: That's why there's a commented out line there. My server returns only JSON, here's the log result: ```Rq body:  [{"_id":"56f9b418657c2d2353611b0f","link":"https://facebook.github.io/flux/","title":"flux"}]```

Comment: remember it is an array `[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return body from the server is still a JSON string. By doing console.log() on a JSON string the escape `\` is removed in the console. It seems you thought the value was parsed, but in reality it wasn't. Run JSON.parse(body) on the response, it should work.

Example: https://jsbin.com/bomehafeki/1/edit?js,console